# How to create TradingView indicators that look like this?

Tags: math, pine-script, trading, indicator, rsi

I've been trying to create similar indicator to this

[This is the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAFuq.png)

I have the code for RSI, Stochastic RSI, MACD and 50/100/200 MA (with crosses), but I couldn't find any information on how to create the visuals like in the reference altough I was studying for quite a long time

Here is the code for these indicators:

50/100/200 MA with crosses (coded by myself)

```
indicator(title="3 EMA with Cross", shorttitle="3EMA Cross", overlay=true)
fast = 50
mid = 100
slow = 200
fastEMA = ta.ema(close, fast)
midEMA = ta.ema(close, mid)
slowEMA = ta.ema(close, slow)

bullishCross = ta.crossover(fastEMA, slowEMA)
bearishCross = ta.crossunder(fastEMA, slowEMA)

if (bullishCross)
    lbl = label.new(bar_index, low, "Golden Cross")
    label.set_color(lbl, color.green)
    label.set_yloc(lbl, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_up)

if (bearishCross)
    lbl = label.new(bar_index, low, "Death Cross")
    label.set_color(lbl, color.red)
    label.set_yloc(lbl, yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_style(lbl, label.style_label_down)
plot(fastEMA, color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(midEMA, color=color.yellow, linewidth=2)
plot(slowEMA, color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```

RSI

```
indicator(title="Relative Strength Index", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2,                 
timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

ma(source, length, type) =>
switch type
    "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
    "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
    "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
    "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
    "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
    "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(14, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["SMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "WMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"

plot(rsi, "RSI", color=#7E57C2)
plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.yellow)
rsiUpperBand = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")
```

MACD

```
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence Divergence", shorttitle="MACD", timeframe="", 
timeframe_gaps=true)
// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ?                 
col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
```

Stochastic RSI

````
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
rsi1 = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
plot(k, "K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, "D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")```

//MACD
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence Divergence", shorttitle="MACD", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `label`s with offset for that. Offset will help you with the placement.

Update the labels with each bar and delete the old bars.

A simple example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script")

rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)

rsi_off = 50
ema50_off = 25

rsi_up_trend = rsi < 30
ema_up_trend = close > ema50

var label l_rsi = na
var label l_ema50 = na

if barstate.islast
    l_rsi := label.new(bar_index - rsi_off, 1, "RSI", color=rsi_up_trend ? color.green : color.red, style=label.style_triangleup, textcolor=color.white)
    l_ema50 := label.new(bar_index - ema50_off, 1, "EMA50", color=ema_up_trend ? color.green : color.red, style=label.style_triangleup, textcolor=color.white)
    
    label.delete(l_rsi[1])
    label.delete(l_ema50[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I reakky helped me, I couldn't find anything related to this